# Feedback on algorithm for Steiner Tree with restrictions

Tags: graph-algorithm, dijkstra, minimum-spanning-tree

For an assignment, I have to create a [Steiner Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_tree_problem).  However, this is not a typical Steiner Tree, as the graph structure we're required to use does not allow insertion of new vertices.  Rather, the test cases define a graph structure of N vertices and M edges while specifically marking X vertices as target nodes.  These are the nodes we have to span while using some, none or all of the unmarked vertices in the graph.

My solution to this problem is

1. Implement [Dijkstra's Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find the shortest path between all the target vertices
2. For each of the shortest paths 1:n

   1. Extract all current selected path vertices into a set
   2. Extract all remaining vertices into a set
   3. For all vertices of the current selected path 1:m

      1. Execute Dijkstra to find shortest path between current vertex and other path's vertices
      2. If this creates a spanning tree, save path and length in priority queue sorted by length value
3. Pop top of priority queue and return path

My issue is that this is an exhaustive search that uses the initial application of Dijkstra to create a reduced set of possible start-end vertices for a shorter path than a minimum spanning tree.

Is there a heuristic or other algorithm that may solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

With some help, I worked out this answer for a similar problem that I had.  Rather than adding new vertices as in a spacial steiner tree problem, the new steiner points in this graph are the vertices that lie along the path between the marked nodes.  For a graph with N vertices, M edges, X require vertices, and S found vertices (vertices along our path):

1. Compute All Pairs Shorest Paths (Floyd-Warshall, Johnson's, whatever)
2. for k in X

   1. remove k from X, insert k into S
   2. for v in (X + S) - Both sets

      1. find the shortest distance from k to v - path P
   3. for u in P (all vertices on the path)

      1. insert u into S
      2. if u exists in k, remove u from k

Now for the wall of text as to what this algorithm does.  We pick a vertex k in X, and then find the minimum distance to the nearest other vertex in the target set X, or in the result set S, and call it v.  Then we follow the path of nodes from {k,u}, inserting them into our result set.  Finally, double check and make sure that any vertices in X that were on the path (shouldn't happen) are removed from X.

Any new vertex that you want to add, c, will have a minimum distance to some node already in your result set S.  Since the nodes already in S are the minimum distance apart, it follows that c will be the minimum distance from any point in S to c.  For example, if you have three nodes, A, B, and C, if A and B are already found to be a minimum distance apart, adding C fulfills the requirement that it is the minimum distance from B, and the minimum distance path from A to C goes through B.

I did some research on the discrete Steiner Tree problem (which is what this is), and this is the best brute force solution that I found.  The main problem is going to be the O(n^3) time it takes to do all pairs shortest paths, but then the construction of the minimum tree should be straightforward and quick, since you just need to look up distance information.  The implementation I wound up working with is [outlined nicely on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm#Path_reconstruction).